# Arcpy.da.UpdateCursor, Error - Sequence size must match size of row

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am trying to use an UpdateCursor fill in a field but I keep getting an error, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? My code is below:

```
import arcpy

fc= "C:\Users\Keri\Desktop\GEP_690\Project Data\FINAL_PROJECT.gdb\NYC_Demographics_2010"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Total1","White","Pct_White"]) as cursor:
    for field in cursor:
        if field[0]==0:
            field[2]=0
        else:
            field[2] = field[1] / field[0]
        cursor.updateRow([field])
print "Complete."

del row

del cursor
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\GEP_662\Lab9.py", line 15, in <module>
    cursor.updateRow([field])
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

Comment: As a side note, `del row` and `del cursor` are not needed when using a cursor in a `with` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I did not know that, just learning  python

Answer (score 7):

Use the `cursor.updateRow(field)` instead of `cursor.updateRow([field])`. You should supply an object, not the list.

Comment: This will solve the problem, but to be a little more specific, field already is a list (an update cursor returns a set of lists, one per row).  When you write [field] you are actually passing a list with one a single entry, and that entry is a list, e.g. [['field1','field2']].

Comment: Thank you Mr.adamn, Now I see why I was getting that error message. You were so helpful!!!!!