# UpdateCursor is updating empty list correctly but NOT updating data in feature class

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, cursor, feature-class

I have looked at other posts and am not able to solve my issue. I'm working with Python 2.7 (must use this ver for work).

I am trying to reformat labels in an attribute column ("ID") and update that column. My current version of the code runs without errors AND when I print the 'labels' list the reformatted edits show. However they do not get populated to my feature class column. I am missing something and/or have a syntax issue.

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Labels.mxd')
fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'RoadCore')[0]

fields = ['ID', 'ADMIN_ORG']
labels = []

def newlabel():
    #newfields = ['ID', 'ADMIN_ORG', 'MAP_ID']
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[1].startswith ('04'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(row[0].replace("-ADMIN","").replace('-A-ADMIN','').replace('-PARKING','')[2:].lstrip('0').replace('.', '-').lstrip(ascii_letters)))
            cursor.updateRow(row)#Many SO posts show this syntax. Populates the list but does not update the feature class data.

            #cursor.updateRow([row])#per SE post
            #https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142965/arcpy-da-updatecursor-error-sequence-size-must-match-size-of-row
            #still errors with TypeError: sequence size mush match size of the row
        #labels.append{row[3]}#Doesn't work
    print(labels)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    newlabel()
```

Comment: You're creating a `labels` list but not using it, you don't change the `row` values, then update the `cursor` with the unchanged `row`.

Comment: How do I implement that? I'm pretty new & have been banging my head. I thought that labels.append was updating the list... I did try cursor.updateRow(labels) and get the same Typeerror: sequence size much match the size of the row.

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify which field you are trying to update.

Comment: @user2856 - I'm trying to update the 'ID' in fields. It is populating the list but not using the labels. This is just a portion, ultimately I need to populate a new field I'm adding but need this to work first. Thanks! (labels.append(row[0]) doesn't work either :(

Comment: Edit your question please, don't add additional info in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You create a `labels` list but don't use it for anything other than `print(labels)`.

You append to this list each time you loop through the cursor, so by the end of the cursor loops, it will contain *all* of the labels, not just the one for the current row.

You don't change the row values, then update the cursor with the unchanged row.  `row[0].replace("-ADMIN","").replace('-A-ADMIN','').replace('-PARKING','')[2:].lstrip('0').replace('.', '-').lstrip(ascii_letters)` doesn't actually change `row`, it just returns a string. You need to DO something with this string.

So what you are actually doing (if I remove the code that does nothing) is:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also, you are updating your cursor outside the scope of your `if` statement, so the cursor updates every single row, not just the ones you actually want to change which will slow your code down.  This won't affect what you are trying to do, you're just updating rows unnecessarily.

Try this:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Labels.mxd')
fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'RoadCore')[0]

fields = ['ID', 'ADMIN_ORG']

def newlabel():

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[1].startswith ('04'):
                row[0] = '{}'.format(row[0].replace("-ADMIN","").replace('-A-ADMIN','').replace('-PARKING','')[2:].lstrip('0').replace('.', '-').lstrip(ascii_letters))
                cursor.updateRow(row) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    newlabel()
```

Comment: Thanks...this helped get closer. Now it is only printing the first row of data though....  D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation>phase2.py
['4'', u'041004']  GOT IT! I moved the print statement over dur dur :)  Thanks for the help, spent way too much time on this.

Comment: Actually now looking at the data it 'cleared' erased all of my ID field to blanks.

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact code you used

Answer (score 0):

It's working great now! Following advice from @user2856 getting rid of unused dictionary and using the row[0] = stuff to update data and moving the cursor.updateRow(row) in line with the IF statements... success!

Here is the working snippet:

```
    enter mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Labels.mxd')
fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'RoadCore')[0]

fields = ['ID', 'ADMIN_ORG']
labels = []

def newlabel():
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as uc:
        for row in uc:
            if row[1] == None:
                pass
            elif row[1].startswith ('04'):#This is populating labels
                row[0] = '{}'.format(row[0].replace("-ADMIN","").replace('-A-ADMIN','').replace('-PARKING','')[2:].lstrip('0').replace('.', '-').lstrip(ascii_letters))
            uc.updateRow(row)
        print(row)
```